# How can I set up a common SFTP directory for certain users, mounted with s3fs?

Tags: sshd, sftp, s3fs

I'm looking to set up a common directory which is writable via SFTP by a certain set of users. This set of users should be able to access only this directory, and only via SFTP.

I have successfully set this up, using the following sshd configuration:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftponly
        ChrootDirectory /mnt/filebucket
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        PermitTunnel no
        X11Forwarding no
        PasswordAuthentication yes   # temporary for testing
```

My users are part of the `sftponly` group, and they can log in and they are successfully chrooted into the directory.

The catch, though, is that I want to mount an S3 bucket (using s3fs) in this /mnt/filebucket directory. Once I mount it, the permissions on the directory change from `drwxr-xr-x  2 root root` (sshd approves for chroot) to `drwxrwxrwx  1 root root` (sshd does *not* approve).

Is there something about how I'm mounting this directory that is causing this issue?

Comment: Have you tried changing the permissions after it's mounted with `chmod`?

Comment: @Patrick yes: `chmod: changing permissions of ‘/mnt/filebucket’: Input/output error`

Comment: If I set the ChrootDirectory to /mnt everything works as expected, but then users need to (cd|click) into the extra `filebucket` directory after logging in. Can this be automated?

Answer (score 0):

> If I set the ChrootDirectory to /mnt everything works as expected, but then users need to (cd|click) into the extra filebucket directory after logging in. Can this be automated?

Yes, you can use `-d` switch to the `internal-sftp`, which will specify the starting directory for users.